# java web application deployment on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, deployment, java

I had developed a java web application on jdk1.5.

I used eclipse IDE for the development purpose. And when am running the application through eclipse, its working properly, no issues am facing. But when am trying to deploy the same application as war file in the same machine's tomcat server, its throwing some error like `Bad version number in .class file` or in some other time i will get error message like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

This is what am getting in the stack trace.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    com.bdisys.auditservice.manager.AuditServiceManager.updateAuditServiceDetails(AuditServiceManager.java:46)
    com.bdisys.auditservice.servlet.AuditServiceHandler.doPost(AuditServiceHandler.java:45)
    com.bdisys.auditservice.servlet.AuditServiceHandler.doGet(AuditServiceHandler.java:34)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

Am attaching my project config for Java compiler settings.

[image]

Can anyone give suggestions to resolve this strange issue.?

Comment: Could you paste the stacktrace here?

Comment: @PetarMinchev Can you please check now..I had updated my question with what am getting in the stacktrace.

Comment: what is AuditServiceManager doing in line 46

Comment: @PetarMinchev In that am just creating an object of another class.

Comment: Please tell me the java version by selecting your project and click on properties for that project context menu and select Java Compiler. And how are you creating your war file(any building tools)?

Comment: @Pokuri am attaching a screen shot of my config. Am not using any building tools to create war file. Just eclipse can do that by clicking on export as war.

Comment: Check that tomcat is also running on JRE 1.5 or above. else change that refer http://www.coderanch.com/t/87379/Tomcat/Change-JRE

Comment: @Pokuri I checked the tomcat catalina.bat, it refer setenv.bat and inside that only JAVA_HOME is set, not JRE_HOME. So i think since JRE_HOME is absent, the same JAVA_HOME is set as JRE_HOME. and JAVA_HOME is point to a java_sdk folder. It contains 2 folders named jre & jre6 in it and i think by default its taking the jre folder. When i set this same jre as JRE_System_Library in eclipse i got the same error - Bad version number problem. So got a solution ..Thanks

Comment: Sorry..dats not get solved.still same exception

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
Bad version number in .class
```

This is caused by JVM incompatibility.

Ensure that you use same Java version for compiling and executing.

Check that your Tomcat installation is using a JRE that matches the JDK 1.5 Version that you used to compile and generate your WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath and libraries are correct? The app not running because not found class AuditServiceManager in package com.bdisys.auditservice.manager (it's an library?)